# VBA Type Mismatch 13 on Clearly Declared Variable

Tags: vba, excel

i have this code working for a month now and it suddenly starting throwing type mismatch 13 on the line i marked. I have been searching for a day now and all the related questions are either cell format or object related.

I think my problem here is neither and it looks so simple and makes me ill to not see it still.

What i tried:

Used application.inputbox method with type, declared the said variable to integer, variant instead of double, completely ommitted the usage of 0 made it 20 and still got the error. Code works except if you input 0 or declare the variable to be zero anyhow. This code has been working for more than a month now. What is the problem?

edit: more info

```
Sub Farincal_OPC_hamyuzde_vs_giriş()

Dim dbs1 As String
Dim dbis1 As String
Dim kayek1 As String
Dim kdn1 As String
Dim ph As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim dd As Integer
Dim ctf As Integer
Dim farin As Double
Dim farinper(18) As Double
Dim a As Integer

dd = MsgBox("question?", vbYesNo)
If dd = vbYes Then GoTo 13
If dd = vbNo Then GoTo 789


13


a = 1                'this resets the array
For a = 1 To 18
farinper(a) = 0
Next a
86

farin = InputBox("0 - PREMIX" & vbNewLine & "1 - etc") 'this holds the choice's number on farin

'THE TYPE MISMATCH HAPPENS ON THE LINE BELOW, AS SOON AS IT CHECKS OUT TO BE 0

    If farin = 4 Or farin = 5 Then 'this is used for the other choices which i deleted above.

'Code DOES NOT continue the line below, type mismatch happens as soon as the above line is run

    a = MsgBox("warning", vbExclamation)

    GoTo 86   'PREMİX CHECK!!!!
    End If
    If farin = 0 Then sheet1.Cells(28, 3) = InputBox("question")
    If farin > 18 Or farin < 0 Then
    MsgBox ("you are wrong")
    GoTo 86
    End If


a = 0
For a = 0 To 18

788
        If farin = a Then farinper(a) = InputBox("more input")
        If farinper(a) < 0 Or farinper(a) > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("more error handle")
        GoTo 788
        End If
Next a


If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(farinper) < 1 Then
MsgBox ("info")
GoTo 86
End If
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(farinper) > 1 Then
MsgBox ("error handle")
GoTo 13
End If

sheet1.Cells(27, 3) = farinper(0) ' PREMİX!!

a = 1

For a = 1 To 18

If a = 3 Or a = 4 Then GoTo 9424 'skip unecessary entry

sheet1.Cells(a + 24, 2) = farinper(a)

9424

Next a
```

Comment: is it that you're missing a `&` after `vbNewLine`? `farin = InputBox("0 - PREMIX" & vbNewLine & "1 - etc")` Also your `If dd = vbNo Then GoTo 789` but the label is actually `788`?

Comment: No i just over deleted ^^ just edited the post

Comment: Ok, well can you edit your question and update the code?

Comment: The type mismatch probably happens because you are supposed to put in an integer in the `0 - PREMIX` InputBox and my guess is that you are entering a non numerical value...?

Comment: nope just 0. dimmed it as integer, variant, set it as farin=0 and used Cdbl(farin) etc. no solution. The value cannot be 0 but can be 0,0001 can be 4 can be -10000000. I am lost

Comment: You're getting the type mismatch error on the If statement, not the InputBox?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As soon as it is checked.

Comment: The InputBox function returns a string, the variable farin is declared as Double and you are testing against an Integer (or probably long) literal. Maybe try declaring farin as String and use CInt(farin) or CLng(farin) to explicitly type cast

Comment: Every other number possible works and checked by the if properly. ie input 4 and it warns, input 1 and rest of the code runs just fine. I tried what you said several times and realized farin accepts 0 if the code is copied to an entirely different workbook. I am lost badly. (ie i used farin=Cdbl(inputbox("whatever")) for what you suggested and failed before)

Comment: Farin is shown as double in locals window with its value just before the if statement is run. What is going on with zero? It is just the 0 and this workbook it is on.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error "Type mismatch" at following line of your code

```
        If farin = a Then farinper(a) = InputBox("more input")
```

when I entered non-numeric character in the InputBox.

If "a" is input of InputBox, "a" can not be assigned to farinper() bacause types of them are "String" and "Double".

I guess that you experience this error.

Comment: No it is not an input. It is just an integer counter. I may have ommitted much of the rest of the code. I will try the pasted version now.

Comment: WOW i just realized. The line does not give type mismatch on a freshly created workbook. It only gives it on the workbook its on. What the hell.